# How to filter a sub array but keep the root content?

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation

Using mongo 3.6

I have a top level object that has attributes that contain array of content.

```
      {
        firstName: "first1",
        lastName: "last1",
        phones: [
          {
            name: "home",
            number: "1800"
          },
          {
            name: "work",
            number: "1888"
          }
        ]
      }
```

and I want to only return 'work' phone numbers, but maintain the root content.

expected result would be :

```
 {
        firstName: "first1",
        lastName: "last1",
        phones: [
          {
            name: "work",
            number: "1888"
          }
        ]
      }
```

The use case is return patients that are on specific medications, but only return those medications and not the complete medication lists.

so I tried this:

```
 {
    $project: {
      phones: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$phones",
          as: "phones",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$phones.name",
              "work"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have to do this often to remove elements of sub arrays so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The schema is still unclear. Please post some sample documents.

Comment: Ok I added some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "phones":{
                $filter:{
                    "input":"$phones",
                    "as":"phone",
                    "cond":{
                        $eq:["$$phone.name","work"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d56d6c632ac518eee84d462"),
    "firstName" : "first1",
    "lastName" : "last1",
    "phones" : [
        {
            "name" : "work",
            "number" : "1888"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was missing the addFields :-( . Thank you!